# Set hint for update to use indexes

Tags: mongodb-java, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

As per documentation it is possible to provide a hint to an update.
Now I'm using the java mongo client and mongo collection to do an update.

For this update I cannot find any way to provide a hint which index to use.
I see for the update I'm doing a COLSCAN in the logs, so wanting to provide the hint.

```
this.collection.updateOne(
    or(eq("_id", "someId"), eq("array1.id", "someId")),
    and(
        addToSet("array1", new Document()),
        addToSet("array2", new Document())
    )
);
```

Indexes are available for both `_id` and `array1.id`
I found out in the logs the query for this update is using a COLSCAN to find the document.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Using AWS DocumentDB, which is MongoDB v3.6

Comment: Is `array1` a field of type "array"?

Comment: Amazon DocumentDB is a separate implementation from the MongoDB server. DocumentDB uses the MongoDB 3.6 wire protocol, but there are number of [functional differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html) and the [supported commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) are a subset of those available in MongoDB 3.6. Support for hinting updates was added in MongoDB 4.2 so I suspect DocumentDB will not have this feature yet, but you'd have to review the DocumentDB documentation or test to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider a document with an array of embedded documents:

```
{ _id: 1, arr: [ { fld1: "x", fld2: 43 }, { fld1: "r", fld2: 80 } ]  }
```

I created an index on `arr.fld1`; this is a Multikey index (indexes on arrays are called as so). The `_id` field already has the default unique index.

The following query uses the indexes on both fields - `arr.fld1` and the `_id`. The *query plan* generated using `explain()` on the query showed an index scan (IXSCAN) for both fields.

```
db.test.find( { $or: [ { _id: 2 }, { "arr.fld1": "m" } ] } )
```

Now the same query filter is used for the ***update operation*** also. So, the update where we add two sub-documents to the array:

```
db.test.update(
  { $or: [ { _id: 1 }, { "arr.fld1": "m" } ] },
  { $addToSet: { arr: { $each: [ { "fld1": "xx" }, { "fld1": "zz" } ] } } }
)
```

Again, the query plan showed that both the indexes are used for the *update* operation. Note, I have not used the ***hint*** for the *find* or the *update* query.

I cannot come to conclusion about what the issue is with your code or indexes (see point *Notes: 1*, below).

**NOTES:**

1. The above observations are based on queries run on a *MongoDB server
   version 4.0* (valid for *version 3.6* also, as I know).
2. The
   [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/method/db.collection.explain/)
   method is used as follows for *find* and *update*:
   `db.collection.explain().find( ... )` and
   `db.collection.explain().update( ... )`.
3. Note that you *cannot* generate a *query plan* using `explain()` for
   `updateOne` method; it is only available for `findAndModify()` and
   `update()` methods. You can get a list of methods that can generate a
   query plan by using the command at *mongo shell*:
   `db.collection.explain().help()`.

*Note on Java Code:*

The Java code to update an array field with multiple sub-document add, is as follows:

```
collection.updateOne(
    or(eq("_id", new Integer(1)), eq("arr.fld1", "m")),
    addEachToSet("arr", Arrays.asList(new Document("fld1", "value-1"), new Document("fld1", "value-2"))
);
```